# Given a Haskell list, return all sub-lists obtained by removing one element

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a Haskell function which takes a list `ls` and returns all sub-lists obtained by removing one element from `ls`. An additional constraint is that the returned list of lists must be in the order of the missing element.

Here is what I have. I know there must be a simpler solution.

```
subOneLists :: [a] -> [[a]]
subOneLists ls = let  helper :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
                      helper _ [] ss = ss
                      helper ps (x:xs) ss = helper ps' xs ss'
                        where ps' = ps ++ [x]
                              ss' = ss ++ [ps ++ xs]
                 in helper [] ls []

λ> subOneLists [1, 2, 3, 4]
[[2,3,4],[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a simpler way to implement it:

```
subOneLists :: [a] -> [[a]]
subOneLists [] = []
subOneLists (x:xs) = xs : map (x :) (subOneLists xs)
```

Comment: This is really clever

Comment: this repeats the old `inits` bug which makes `(last $ subOneLists xs !! n)` quadratic in `n`. My version as well as the newer, corrected version of `inits` in the library makes it linear.

Answer (score 7):

List as an abstract concept can have many representations.

In particular, with a list being represented by its "zipper" - a pairing of a reversed prefix and a suffix, it becomes possible to have a linear solution to this problem, as opposed to the quadratic one which is unavoidable with the plain linear representation :

```
picks :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
picks []     = []
picks (x:xs) = go [x] xs
   where
   go pref suff@(x:xs) = (pref,suff) : go (x:pref) xs
   go pref []          = [(pref,[])]
```

Using this, your problem becomes

```
foo = map (\(a,b) -> revappend (tail a) b) . picks

revappend a b = foldl (flip (:)) b a
```

This is of course again quadratic, but maybe you could keep the prefixes reversed, to stay linear:

```
import Control.Arrow (first)

foo' = map (first tail) . picks               -- or,
 --  = map (\(x,y) -> (tail x, y)) . picks
```

Answer (score 7):

Look out for standard functions that can help you!

```
Prelude Data.List> let subOneLists ls = zipWith (++) (inits ls) (tail $ tails ls)
Prelude Data.List> subOneLists [1, 2, 3, 4]
[[2,3,4],[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,3]]
```

This uses the fact that the `inits`- and `tails`-elements at corresponding index always recombine to the original list, but with a variably splitting point:

```
Prelude Data.List> let ls = [0..7] in mapM_ print (zip (inits ls) (tails ls))
([],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
([0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
([0,1],[2,3,4,5,6,7])
([0,1,2],[3,4,5,6,7])
([0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7])
([0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7])
([0,1,2,3,4,5],[6,7])
([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[7])
([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[])
```

If you now “shift up” that `tails`, by dropping its head, you effectively lose the head of each of the *contained* lists:

```
Prelude Data.List> let ls = [0..7] in mapM_ print (zip (inits ls) (tail $ tails ls))
([],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
([0],[2,3,4,5,6,7])
([0,1],[3,4,5,6,7])
([0,1,2],[4,5,6,7])
([0,1,2,3],[5,6,7])
([0,1,2,3,4],[6,7])
([0,1,2,3,4,5],[7])
([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[])
```

And that can just be `++` combined with the `inits` again.

Comment: makes me wonder that maybe there should be `revinits` in the library somewhere...

Comment: Would probably make more sense to make that a rewrite rule for `tails . reverse`, if even necessary.

Comment: I meant `reversed_inits [1..] !! 10 == [10,9..1]`. :) (i.e. `map reverse . inits` but linear)

Comment: Ok, `reverse . tails . reverse`... yeah, that's ah bit _meh_. Still – I don't think it's good to pack `base` with every combination of reversal and disassembly. If you use any of these, then it's probably not optimal for performance anyway (compared to something `Data.Vector` based), and if performance isn't that critical then just combine simple list functions.

Comment: see my updated comment. It's supposed to be linear, that's the point. and work for infinite inputs too.

Comment: well, yeah, `scanl (flip (:)) []` does the job, so maybe there's no need for it indeed. :)